# dynamic filename and setting of variable

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am dynamically genearting filename in Informatica with filename option in target structure and I am also setting the value of this dynamic filename to a maping variable - SETVARIABLE($$m_FILENAME,FILENAME) But what I see is the filename is generated with different name and varaible is set with different name.

target file - E1_ONBOARDING_0705016055915.txt
varaible - E1_ONBOARDING_0705016054509.txt

I do not understand why few seconds of difference in the timestamp.
When i debug it, it shows same value.

Please help

Comment: How are you generating the filename?

Comment: logic for filename is : 'E1_ONBOARDING_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MMDDYYYHHMISS')||'.txt'

Comment: Try one thing: create a variable port and assign only SYSDATE to it. Then use the variable port in the expression to generate filename.

Comment: Doesnt work either..

Comment: it was a mistake in code- instead of mmddyyyy it was mmddyyy

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try `'E1_ONBOARDING_'||TO_CHAR(SESSSTARTTIME,'MMDDYYYHHMISS')||'.txt' ;` Replacing *`SYSDATE`* with *`SESSSTARTTIME`*.

*`SESSSTARTTIME`* will take the value of time when the session starts and remains same for the session whereas *SYSDATE* varies within the Session.